# Access updated values in prefetched self recursion set

Tags: django, recursion, updates, prefetch, django-2.0

I have a model:

```
class Vertex(models.Model):                                                                      
  pmap = models.ForeignKey('PMap',on_delete=models.CASCADE)                                                   
  elevation = models.FloatField(default=0)                                         
  flow_sink = models.ForeignKey(                                                                 
      'Vertex',                                                                                  
      on_delete=models.CASCADE,                                                                  
      related_name='upstream',                                                                   
      null=True)
```

And another model with the following function:

```
class PMap(models.Model):
  def compute_flux(self, save=False):
    vertices = self.vertex_set.order_by('-elevation').prefetch_related('flow_sink')

    # Init flux
    for vert in vertices:
      vert.flux = 1.0 / len(vertices)

    # Add flux from current to the downstream node.
    for vert in vertices:
      if vert.id != vert.flow_sink.id:
        vert.flow_sink.flux = vert.flux
```

The function `compute_flux()` is supposed to add the `flux` value from the currently visited vertex to its `flow_sink` (which in turn is another vertex). It should do this recursively, so that when it reaches a vertex that has had its `flux` updated previously, it should yield that value to its own `flow_sink`.

Sadly, this doesn't work. All vertices end up with the initial `flux = 1.0 / len(vertices)`. I think the reason is that we're updating the vertices in the prefetched set `prefetch_related('flow_sink')` rather than the vertices in the `vertices` set. Thus `vert.flux` in the last loop will never have any other value than the one set in the first (init) loop.

How can I fix this or work around the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `Vertex` objects you loaded with `prefetch_related` are not the same *objects* as the one in your `vertices`. Yes, those two objects will be equal, a `v1 == v2` check will succeed. This because Django checks if the models are the same, and the primary keys, but not the other value. Changes made to one of the `Vertex` objects will not reflect in the other model.

We can solve this by maintaining a dictionary that maps the `pk`s to the corresponding vertex, like:

```
class PMap(models.Model):

    # ...

    def compute_flux(self, save=False):
        vertices = self.vertex_set.order_by('-elevation')
        ver_dic = { v.pk: v for v in vertices }

        for vert in vertices:
            vert.flux = 1.0 / len(vertices)

        # Add flux from current to the downstream node.
        for vert in vertices:
            if vert.flow_sink_id != vert.pk:
                vertices[flow_sink_id].flux += vert.flux
```

You probably also forgot to write `+=` instead of <s>`=`</s>: the latter will have no effect, since we already assigned that value to the vertex.

We here thus cache the `Vertex` objects in a dictionary, and instead of using the result of a prefetched value, we use the dictionary value.

Here we assume that all vertices are part of `vertices` queryset, if that is not the case, we can still let thus work, by constructing a dictionary that "lazily" is populated as new items arrive:

```
class PMap(models.Model):

    # ...

    def compute_flux(self, save=False):
        vertices = self.vertex_set.order_by('-elevation').prefetch_related('flow_sink')
        ver_dic = { v.pk: v for v in vertices }

        # if some flow_sink vertices are not part of the PMap
        for vert in vertices:
            if vert.flow_sink_id not in ver_dic:
                ver_dic[vert.flow_sink_id] = vert.flow_sink

        for vert in vertices:
            vert.flux = 1.0 / len(vertices)

        # Add flux from current to the downstream node.
        for vert in vertices:
            if vert.flow_sink_id != vert.pk:
                vertices[flow_sink_id].flux += vert.flux
```

Note that if you do not save the object however, setting the `.flux` will have no effect, and if you later fetch the vertices again, then these vertices will of course still have the old value.

Comment: Ah, saving is done some steps later, but removed here to produce a minimal example, good to point out however :) I had a solution similar to this in mind, but since it is not as elegant as I would like I posted the question. I'll mark the solution as accepted because it's correct and probably the best one under the circumstances. Thanks!